# How can I solve a problem with false spam report on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am admin in a few pages on Facebook where me and other admins post links that lead to our blogs. In the last couple of days I noticed that when someone clicks on the link to my blog Facebook warns them about spam! And that happens with each click! A message appears: "**You are leaving Facebook: Facebook thinks this site might be unsafe. If you are not familiar with it, please provide feedback by marking it as spam (you will be brought back to Facebook).**"
How can I solve this? I hate it because my blog pageviews plummeted since this is happening and the most important thing is - I'm not spamming! I post my links in pages related to the subject. And I don't even post that often... This happens ONLY with my blog, other links posted on the wall of the page open normally.
I wanted to contact Facebook developers by e-mail, by as I notices there is no such possibility. Someone, help please.

Comment: you are getting that message because at one point you sent someone in facebook your link and this person did not like it and reported your link as a spam to facebook. how can you solve this....I am not sure?

Answer (score -1):

If its tumblr or blogspot, or pretty much anything using a sub domain, they like to block it whether its spam or not, the only way around it is to have a lot of people mark it as not spam so it becomes trusted.

Comment: You should add a reference of that, otherwise it will remain a statement. Welcome to Web Applications !!